# Replace MPICH Installation by OpenMPI

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi, mpich

I currently have `MPICH` (release 3.1.4) installed on my machine (running Mac OS X 10.10.5). I would like to remove it and install `OpenMPI` instead but could find no instructions online on how to uninstall `MPICH`.

Is it sufficient to simply delete `MPICH`'s directory? If so, where can I find it? I thought I had installed it in `usr/local` and did find some MPI-related files there (in a folder named `include`) but nothing that seemed like it was the whole thing.

Also, I am planning to use `OpenMPI` together with Intel's `c++` compiler. Is there some preferred order of installation of these two?

Comment: This depends highly on the system you installed it on, and the installation method you used.

Comment: @haraldkl Indeed I forgot to mention that. I am working on OS X Version 10.10.5. To install `MPICH`, I downloaded `mpich-3.1.4.tar.gz` from the [MPICH download page](http://www.mpich.org/downloads/) and followed the installation instructions.

Comment: You should use homebrew if you don't know how to uninstall packages manually.

Comment: @Jeff The problem is I only learned about homebrew when googling for how to uninstall `MPICH`. Homebrew sounds like a good idea for the future, however. Is it possible to install Intel's `c++` compiler via homebrew and would you recommend that?

Comment: You cannot install the Intel compiler via Homebrew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juste type `make uninstall` from the directory you compiled. That should do it.
Regarding openMPI and the Intel compiler, better installing the compiler before ans using it to build the package, but that's not compulsory, using GCC will do as well.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'the directory you compiled'. Do you mean the directory that is created when unpacking `mpich-3.1.4.tar.gz`? I just tried that and was met with `make: *** No rule to make target uninstall.  Stop.`.

Comment: You probably either freshly unpacked it or did a `make distclean` at some stage. If it's the case, then you need to first do a `./configure blah` with 'blah' being the configure options you used when installing the package... Once the the configure step done, `make uninstall` should just work.

Comment: You're right. I did delete and then reunpack  `mpich-3.1.4.tar.gz`. [Note for others who might read this thread and don't remember the options they passed during the first configuration: They can be retrieved from `.bash_history` which is located (but hidden) in the user directory.] After reconfiguration, I tried `make uninstall` again and received three error messages, the last one being `make: *** [uninstall-recursive] Error 1`. Previously it had said `rm: opa_util.h: Permission denied` which I assumed had caused this error so I tried `sudo make uninstall`. [Ran out of characters...]

Comment: `sudo make uninstall` ran a lot longer and finished with `Making uninstall in examples` and `make[1]: Nothing to be done for uninstall.`. I assume that means deinstallation was successful?

Comment: Yes apparently, that did it.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for your help. To be sure, I ran `mpiexec --version` and got `-bash: mpiexec: command not found`. So now its safe to install the Intel `c++` compiler and then ÒpenMPI` using homebrew, right?